# People say "Wazzup?" Is it proper?

Tags: slang

People usually say this as *Wazzup?* But I think it is not proper. Would it be better to replace it with What's up? Why or why not?

Comment: What context???

Comment: Hi! Welcome to ELL! Can you please provide us a little bit of context? So we can help you in a better way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Wazzup" is informal nonstandard vocabulary that certainly would be legitimate in the proper context.  On the other end of the scale is "How do you do?"

"Wazzup" is common among young people the United States, and it first appeared among black people as an informal greeting.  It is often given a unique intonation for effect.

Answer (score 1):

> People say this usually as wazzup but i think it is not proper

It's not a form that has made its way into most dictionaries yet.  It may do eventually (as "dunno" has) as a representation of colloquial pronunciation.

> would it be better to replace it with *What's up?*

That's a matter of opinion.  I would spell it "What's up?".  However, if you were part of a social group where "Wazzup" was the accepted spelling, it is at least possible that insisting on the full version in an informal context might be interpreted as less warm or less convivial than using the spelling that everyone else was using.

If you are talking about pronunciation rather than spelling, something like "wazzup" or "wozzup" is sometimes used colloquially and it should not be regarded as improper in informal contexts.

Comment: It is of curse more than possible that one's social group is such that even "wazzup" is over-formal, and a brief "sup" or "zup" is de rigueur. Slang is more volatile than can ever be completely and accurately documented.